# In Scrapy, how do I pass the urls generated in one class to the next class in the script?

Tags: python, scrapy

The following is my spider's code:

```
import scrapy


class ProductMainPageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ProductMainPageSpider'
    start_urls = ['http://domain.com/main-product-page']

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('article.isotopeItem'):
            yield {
                'title': product.css('h3 a::text').extract_first().encode("utf-8"),
                'category': product.css('h6 a::text').extract_first(),
                'img': product.css('figure a img::attr("src")').extract_first(),
                'url': product.css('h3 a::attr("href")').extract_first()
            }


class ProductSecondaryPageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ProductSecondaryPageSpider'
    start_urls = """ URLS IN product['url'] FROM PREVIOUS CLASS """

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('article.isotopeItem'):
            yield {
                'title': product.css('h3 a::text').extract_first().encode("utf-8"),
                'thumbnail': product.css('figure a img::attr("src")').extract_first(),
                'short_description': product.css('div.summary').extract_first(),
                'description': product.css('div.description').extract_first(),
                'gallery_images': product.css('figure a img.gallery-item ::attr("src")').extract_first()
            }
```

The first class/part works correctly if I remove the second class/part. It generates my json file correctly with the items requested in it. However, the website I need to crawl is a two-parter. It has a product archive page that shows a products as a thumbnail, title, and category (and this info is not in the next page). Then if you click on one of the thumbnails or titles you get sent to a single product page where there is specific info on the product.

There are a lot of products so I would like to pipe (yield?) the urls in product['url'] to the second class as the "start_urls" list. But I simply don't know how to do that. My knowledge doesn't go far enough to even know what I'm missing or what is going wrong so that I can find a solution.

Check out on line 20 what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create two spiders for this - you can simply go to the next url and carry over your item i.e.:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['name'] = response.xpath("//name/text()").extract()
    next_page_url = response.xpath("//a[@class='next']/@href").extract_first()
    yield Request(next_page_url, 
                  self.parse_next,
                  meta={'item': item}  # carry over our item
                 )

def parse_next(self, response):
    # get our carried item from response meta
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['description'] = response.xpath("//description/text()").extract()
    yield item
```

However if for some reason you realy want to split logic of these two steps you can simply save the results in a file (a json for example: `scrapy crawl first_spider -o results.json`) and open/iterate through it in your second spider in `start_requests()` class method which would yield urls, i.e.:

```
import json
from scrapy import spider

class MySecondSpider(spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        # this overrides `start_urls` logic
        with open('results.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
        for item in data:
            yield Request(item['url'])
```

Comment: I don't get where the "MyItem()" part came from. What is that? Your answer actually just confused me more than before.

Comment: @AdrianoBatista dude, `MyItem` is just a placeholder name for whatever your `scrapy.Item` class is called, you can of course replace it with a simple dictionary but generally you want to stick with `scrapy.Item`. If you are really confused by this answer you should give the tutorial a go to get familiar with the base concepts of spiders, items and requests: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html